# Jquery Controller - User input

Tags: jquery, controller, user-input

I am trying to insert user input into the controller url.

Essentially, variables 'yearReaturned' and 'categoryReturned' will hold user input and insert into the variable 'controlUrl'.

controlUrl should end up being:

"/api/ExpiationsWebAPI?category=01&year=2017"

However, my code doesn't work and just returns monthData as an empty list.

Any help would be amazing.

```
var yearReturned = 01;
var categoryReturned = 2017;

var controlUrl = new String;
controlUrl = "/api/ExpiationsWebAPI?category=" + categoryReturned + "&year=" + yearReturned;



$(document).ready(function () {

    //Function to retrieve data from URL and return it as JSON array of objects
    $(function graphDataIn() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: controlUrl,
            success: function (graphData) {
                console.log("Graph Data loaded", graphData)
                monthData = graphData;

            }
        })
            .done(function () {
                alert("Success");
            })
            .fail(function () {
                alert("Fail");
            })
            .always(function () {
                alert("Complete");
            })
    });
});
```

Comment: Does your done function trigger?

Comment: Note that numbers with leading zeros will get evaluated without the leading zeros so `01` will just be `1` when added to the url string. Try it in quotes as `yearReturned = "01";`

Comment: Also you seem to have the values of the variables  backwards compared to desired output

Comment: The done function triggers.
Tried the quotation marks and nothing.

Comment: Do you see anything in the console.log success function of ajax ? And you are sending the URL as `01` ?

Comment: The code works perfectly when I put the URL in manually. Like this:      
```/api/ExpiationsWebAPI?category=01&year=2017 ```    
But the ```01``` and ```2017``` need to be changeable. Any ideas? Am I inserting the variables incorrectly for controlUrl?

Comment: Did you fix the reversed variables? Open your browser console (F12) and inspect the actual request in network tab. Can see the url used, status, response body etc. If server code chokes will see a 500 status, have to narrow down what part is not working properly

Comment: @charlietfl , good pick up!! It's fixed. Such a noob move haha. Legend

Comment: No worries.... lots and lots of issues can go wrong. Over time they are easier to spot. Learning how to use the debugging tools is also as valuable as learning how to write the code itself